# How can I indent my code in Python with \t

Tags: python, indentation

I'm new to python and was having trouble with a dice rolling game. I want  the outputs of attacker and defender health to be on the opposite side of the screen instead of under the other output. Is there anyway to indent my output, because when I try to, all I get is str and int errors.

My code:[image]

Current output:[image]

Comment: Take a look at the different python print options: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Comment: I'd also check this out: https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/

Comment: Please include (copy/paste) the text of your code in the question, instead of the link to the 1st image.

Comment: Oof strongly **strongly** recommend you ditch Python2 immediately. Work with Python3, Python2 is legacy.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding print this much times you can try adding `\n` after the text in the string
Ex- `print("The Quick Brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \n\n")`
What you may try for tab
`print("attacker health: \t\t Defender Health\n",attacker_health,"\t\t\t\t",defender_health)`
You may alter the no. Of `\t` based on your screen size. 
You should try `\n` and `\t` instead of typing `print` this much times. 
Hope this helps you out.

Comment: If your issue is resolved then please close the thread or tell if any further help is required.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python3's inbuilt string formating, you can print them side by side (that is how I understood from your question).

```
print('{name1}:{health1} \t\t\t\t\t {name2}:{health2}'.format(name1=str(dice1 + dice2 + dice3),health1=attacker_health,name2=str(dice4 = dice5),health2=defender_health))
```

In the above solution everything within `{}` is a placeholder for variable which are supplied as keyword arguments to `format` method. Hope this helps.

Comment: While this might answer the author's question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.